# Show there exists a constant such that the inequality holds

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove there exists a  constant $c \in (0,1)$  ($c$ should depend on $n$) such that

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^3\cdot x_{i+1} \le c \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4$$

holds for all  real numbers $x_i$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0$ and $x_{n+1}=x_1$.

Comment: Should the same $c$  be used for all possible $\{x_1,\ldots, x_{n+1}\}$, or may we choose a different $c$ for a different set of $x_i$'s?

Comment: should be the same for all $x_i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holder's inequality with $p=4/3$ and $q=4$ shows that $\sum x_j^3x_{j+1}\le\sum|x_j^3x_{j+1}|\le \sum x_j^4$.

If we have equality then the condition for equality in Holder says that $|x_{j+1}|=c|x_j|$ for some $c>0$. Hence $|x_1|=c^n|x_1|$, so $c=1$. So all the $x_j$ have the same absolute value. Assume not all the $x_j$ vanish. Then none of them vanish; equality in the first inequality shows that  then we must have $x_j^3x_{j+1}> 0$ for all $j$. That is, $x_jx_{j+1}>0$. So all the $x_j$ have the same sign, hence $\sum x_j\ne0$.

So: $\sum x_j^3x_{j+1}<1 $ for every $(x_j)$ with $\sum x_j^4=1$ and $\sum x_j=0$. Compactness gives qed.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this will give the inequality with $c = 1$. I assume that you apply Hölder's inequality to the absolute values of the $x_i$?

Comment: Yes. Yes: $|\sum x_j^3x_{j+1}|\le \sum|x_j|^3|x_{j+1}|$, while $|x_j^4|=x_j^4$.

Comment: Sure. I am just asking because the question claims that the inequality holds with a $c \in (0, 1)$. One probably has to use $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0$ ...

Comment: Missed $c\in(0,1)$, sorry.

Comment: I think this one's right...

Comment: Or rather this one...

Comment: I'm still confused by $x_j^3 x_{j+1} > 0$. Can you flesh this out?

Comment: @nayrb That follows from equaity in the first inequality. If $\sum a_j = \sum |a_j|$ then $a_j\ge 0$ for all $j$. Hence if $\sum a_j = \sum|a_j|$ and all the $a_j$ have the same absolute value then $a_j>0$ for all $j$ or $a_j=0$ for all $j$.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thanks. I like your answer!